# InfluxDB integral gives high value after missing data

Tags: influxdb

I am storing Amps, Volts and Watts in influxdb in a measurement/table called "Power". The frequency of update is approx every second. I can use the integral function to get power usage (in Amp Hour or Watt Hour) on an hourly basis. This is working very nicely, so I can get a graph of power used each hour over a 24 hour period. My SQL is below.

The issue is if there is a gap in the data then I get a huge spike in the result when it returns. eg if data was missing from 3pm to 5.45 pm, then the 5 pm result shows a huge spike. Reason I can see is there is close to 3 hours gap, so it just calculates the area under the graph and lumps it into the 5 PM value. Can I avoid that?

`SELECT INTEGRAL(Watts) FROM Power WHERE time > now() - 24h GROUP BY time(1h)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Influx. It turns out that `integral()` doesn't support `fill()` as noted by Yuri Lachin in the comments.

Since you're grouping by hours anyway, then the average value of the power (watts) for the hour happens to be equal to the energy consumption for the hour (watt-hours), so you can use the `mean()` value here and you *should* get the correct result.

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT mean("load_power") AS "load"
FROM "power_readings"
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY time(1h) fill(0)
```

For daily numbers I can go back to using `integral()` because I rarely have gaps of data that span multiple days, so there's no filler needed.

Since you can use the `fill()` function in this query, you can decide what makes the most sense of the various options (see https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill)

Comment: I ended up getting my application that inserts the data to insert the integrated values also. So I now have a column (or whatever influx calls it) called watt_hour. This will contain the number of watt hours consumed in the small 10 second interval. I can now just sum those values up over an hour, so if data is missing then it is missing from this column also.

Comment: It's been a while since I solved this problem. Looking back at it a unit of watt hour per 10 seconds is a highly ludicrous unit. It's actually the same thing as 10 joules so I should have just stored joules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fill() in group by section of query (see docs for [Influx fill() usage](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/data_exploration#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill)).
In your case fill(none) or fill(0) should do the job.

Comment: I agree this definitely feels like something that `fill()` should fix, with different results depending on what you want, however I've tried a few different values for `fill()` (0, null, none) and haven't seen a difference in the results with a very similar query as @MikeKulls. Any chance there's some more info on `integral` that can help resolve this weirdness?

Comment: Ha! Docs state that `integral()` doesn't support `fill()`. Using `SELECT_clause FROM ( SELECT_statement ) [...]` with fill(0) in inner select and integral() in outer query might do the trick. Smth like: `select integral(CleanWatts) from (select mean((Watts) as CleanWatts ... group by time(1h) fill(0) ) group by time(1h)` .

Comment: I had a feeling it didn't support it due to a bug -- but if it doesn't by design, that makes more sense. I tried using a nested query that would do the fill and integrating over that, but no change in the query results unfortunately. I ended up hacking this by relying on `mean()` (effectively getting the area under the curve by making a box from the average value for the height and window size for the width). I don't love it, but it seems to work.